# SED "No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, script, sed

So, I am an intermediate linux user, I have just discovered sed and want to use it to automate some configuration during my usual install/configure script.

I have scrolled through all of the forums to locate an issue similar to mine, however I have not seen many using the same format as I am and I am not sure why. I came to the script I have below through looking at a number of other sed scripts and using the ones that worked with what I am trying to do. Then I put it in a script and it throws the error.

I am unable to locate the issue in this sed script:

```
sudo sed -i 's/#AllowTcpForwarding yes/AllowTcpForwarding no/g' "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
sudo sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/g' "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
sudo sed -i 's/X11Forwarding yes/#X11Forwarding yes/g' "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
sudo sed -i 's/#StrictModes yes/StrictModes yes/g' "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
sudo sed -i 's/#IgnoreRhosts yes/IgnoreRhosts yes/g' "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
sudo sed -i 's/#HostbasedAuthentication no/HostbasedAuthentication no/g' "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
sudo sed -i 's/#RhostsRSAAuthentication no/RhostsRSAAuthentication no/g' "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
```

I have also written the command like:

```
sudo sed -i 's/#AllowTcpForwarding yes/AllowTcpForwarding no/g;s/#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/g;s/X11Forwarding yes/#X11Forwarding yes/g;s/#StrictModes yes/StrictModes yes/g;s/#IgnoreRhosts yes/IgnoreRhosts yes/g;s/#HostbasedAuthentication no/HostbasedAuthentication no/g;s/#RhostsRSAAuthentication no/RhostsRSAAuthentication no/g' "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
```

I get the same error:

```
: No such file or directoryhd_config
```

On both when run in a script with other arguments that all complete with no issues. I can run both of the commands successfully by themselves.

The full script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Title:    Ubuntu Setup
# Author:   Matthew Williams
# Date:     10/31/2016
echo "***Ubuntu Setup Script Log***" `date +%d%m%Y_%H:%M.%S`  | tee UbuntuSetupLog.txt
sudo apt-get install -y libpcsclite1 pcscd pcsc-tools libssl-dev libpam0g-dev pkg-config libpcsclite-dev gdebi opensc unity-tweak-tool gnome-do openssh-server openssh-client byobu | tee -a UbuntuSetupLog.txt
echo "***Files Installed***" `date +%d%m%Y_%H:%M.%S`  | tee -a UbuntuSetupLog.txt
#
# Configure Networking / SSH
#
echo "***Configuring Networking/SSH***" | tee -a UbuntuSetupLog.txt
#
sudo sed -i 's/#AllowTcpForwarding yes/AllowTcpForwarding no/g;s/#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/g;s/X11Forwarding yes/#X11Forwarding yes/g;s/#StrictModes yes/StrictModes yes/g;s/#IgnoreRhosts yes/IgnoreRhosts yes/g;s/#HostbasedAuthentication no/HostbasedAuthentication no/g;s/#RhostsRSAAuthentication no/RhostsRSAAuthentication no/g' "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
sudo service sshd restart 2>&1 | tee -a UbuntuSetupLog.txt
#
echo "***Configuring Networking/SSH Complete***" `date +%d%m%Y_%H:%M.%S`  | tee -a UbuntuSetupLog.txt
#
echo "***Script Complete***"
```

The full return is:

```
***Ubuntu Setup Script Log*** 02112016_15:28.38
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
byobu is already the newest version (5.106-0ubuntu1).
libpam0g-dev is already the newest version (1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2).
libpcsclite-dev is already the newest version (1.8.14-1ubuntu1).
libpcsclite1 is already the newest version (1.8.14-1ubuntu1).
pkg-config is already the newest version (0.29.1-0ubuntu1).
gdebi is already the newest version (0.9.5.7ubuntu1).
gnome-do is already the newest version (0.95.3-5).
opensc is already the newest version (0.15.0-1ubuntu1).
pcsc-tools is already the newest version (1.4.25-1).
pcscd is already the newest version (1.8.14-1ubuntu1).
unity-tweak-tool is already the newest version (0.0.7ubuntu2).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.5).
openssh-client is already the newest version (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1).
openssh-server is already the newest version (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
***Files Installed*** 02112016_15:28.38
***Configuring Networking/SSH***
: No such file or directoryhd_config
***Configuring Networking/SSH Complete*** 02112016_15:28.38
***Script Complete***
```

I need this script to automate a number of other machines. I know there are better methods and everyone has their own favorite way to to it. My only question is what am I doing wrong in sed? I am unsure what I need to do to change this script and I have been looking online fruitlessly for about a week.

I believe the error is in the way I am calling the file but not sure how else to do it.

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com. Just flagged for migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script was saved using CR+LF (Windows) line endings. The shell does not understand those – it uses only LF as the line ending marker, and the CR becomes part of the *command*. Thus:

- Your logs are being written to the file `UbuntuSetupLog.txt<CR>`. (Unfortunately both CR and LF are allowed in file names...)
- Your *sed* commands are trying to edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config<CR>`, and the CR byte mangles the error message when it's being printed (acting as an actual carriage return).

Use `dos2unix` or `frodos` to convert the script. Or if you prefer:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' myscript.sh
```

Comment: I'll try that and return the result.

Comment: This was the issue, I thank you for locating my stupid mistake. I was coding this in Notepad++ on a different machine than my normal one. I forgot to do the EOL Conversion since I was on a windows machine at the time.

For those that need that setting. It is located in Edit>EOL Conversion.

Comment: Same issue on my end, spent an hour trying to figure it out.  Was creating sh scripts in VSCode on Windows and uploading them to a linux based container.  One clue was that they show up as `^M` characters in `vi` editor on linux.  Fixed by selecting `LF` in VSCode footer menu, instead of the default `CRLF`